# Ruby: self keyword in class definition

Tags: ruby, self

Is replacing self.name.split  with  @name.split  the same thing?

```
class Person
  attr_accessor :name

  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end

  def normalize_name
    self.name.split(" ").collect{|w| w.capitalize}.join(" ")
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it has the same outcome, because you defined a `attr_accessor` which gives you getter and setter methods

```
class Person
  def name
    @name
  end

  def name=(str)
    @name = str
  end
end
```

so you can call the function `name` using `self` receiver but if you get rid of the `attr_accessor` from your class you can't use `self.name` to get the value of `name`

```
class Person  

  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end

  def normalize_name
    self.name.split(" ").collect{|w| w.capitalize}.join(" ")
  end

end

p = Person.new('John Doe')
p.normalize_name
NoMethodError: undefined method `name' for #<Person:0x00557e98300f68 @name="John Doe">
```

Comment: One caveat in using `@foo` vs `self.foo` is that if you typo `@foo` to something like like `@fooo` you will get a nil value, but `self.fooo` will tell you that the method is not defined. Newer ruby versions might give you a warning about `@foo` if it gets used before it ever gets set, and warnings are turned on.

Comment: Another caveat is, you can add conditions/guards/special actions/tracking etc in `self.foo`, all of which is ignored by `@foo`. For example, if you decide that whenever you set `Person#name`, you also send information to `census_bureau`, but you forgot that there's one place where you used `@name = ...` instead of `self.name = ...`, then `census_bureau` might get angry once it discovers it doesn't have all the data you promised. Always using `self.name` except inside accessors themselves is a good practice; you can relax it when you know you intentionally want to avoid guards, but comment it!